# Auto-create branch if on another branch prior to committing with git

Tags: git, githooks

I have a branch, lets say `master`. I do not have `master` pushes restricted. Is there a way to have it say that if a commit is accidentally done on the `master` branch (or another branch) that a new branch is automatically created and the commits are in there?

Example workflow:

1. Clone the repo `master` branch.
2. Makes lots of changes
3. Does `git commit -am ...`

I want to hook into #3 and create a new branch if the person is committing on `master` (or some other "marked" branch).

If it's not possible, does one just block commits at `master`?

Comment: Switching branches automatically on commit would perhaps be annoying and confusing, especially for new users. If needed, consider setting up your remote so that you can block pushes to the `master` branch. GitHub has some support for this using "protected branches". If you are self-hosting, [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) provides fine-grained access control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating a `pre-commit` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROTECTEDBRANCH="master"

CURRENTBRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if [ "$PROTECTEDBRANCH" == "$CURRENTBRANCH" ]; then
    RANDOMBRANCH=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)

    git checkout -b $RANDOMBRANCH
fi
```

I saved it in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`; it works as expected.

Comment: You *can* do this; as you have seen, it works. I would find Git creating a random branch name for me much more obnoxious than Git simply griping that I hadn't created a significant name myself first, though. So I'd rather set up a pre-commit hook that checks and prints a complaint and exits nonzero.